# How can I use a xcom value to configure max_active_tis_per_dag for the TriggerDagRunOperator in Airflow 2.3.x?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

**Dear Apache Airflow experts,**

I am currently trying to make the parallel execution of Apache Airflow 2.3.x DAGs configurable via the DAG run config.

When executing below code the DAG creates two tasks - for the sake of my question it does not matter what the other DAG does.

Because max_active_tis_per_dag is set to 1, the two tasks will be run one after another.

What I want to achieve: I want to provide the result of get_num_max_parallel_runs (which checks the DAG config, if no value is present it falls back to 1 as default) to max_active_tis_per_dag.

I would appreciate any input on this!

*Thank you in advance!*

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from datetime import datetime

with DAG(
        'aaa_test_controller',
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        catchup=False
) as dag:

    @task
    def get_num_max_parallel_runs(dag_run=None):
        return dag_run.conf.get("num_max_parallel_runs", 1)

    trigger_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator.partial(
        task_id="trigger_dependent_dag",
        trigger_dag_id="aaa_some_other_dag",
        wait_for_completion=True,
        max_active_tis_per_dag=1,
        poke_interval=5
    ).expand(conf=['{"some_key": "some_value_1"}', '{"some_key": "some_value_2"}'])
```

Comment: Your code seem to have syntax error, can you please correct it like TriggerDagRunOperator doesn't any partial function !

Comment: Also can you please include the code of aaa_some_other_dag, it is unclear to me what you want to achieve

Comment: What do you mean by "TriggerDagRunOperator doesn't any partial function"?

Comment: The aaa_some_other_dag only prints the provided conf to the console. What I am trying to do is set aaa_some_other_dag based on the result of get_num_max_parallel_runs.

Comment: so you mean to say depending upon the value of task get_num_max_parallel_runs , you trigger the other dag this number

Comment: Exactly. Depending on the number I want run run n tasks in parallel (or by default only 1 meaning nothing in parallel). It felt like an easy thing to do, but for some reason all potential solutions I tried do not work. Seems like some special restrictions apply for max_active_tis_per_dag (as one of the "partial" parameters).